# Ceiling Fan Universal Remote Wall Switch Install... Which wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Let me first state that I am very green to anything electrical. I know enough to hopefully not kill myself, such as to turn off power at circuit breaker AND to still test wires and switches with a multimeter or similar.

I purchased a Hampton Bay Universal Remote Wall Switch to control my fan from the Wall.

Switch URL:
[Link to Switch I bought](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-B...050H/202801200)

The fan I am replacing in the living room is currently wired to be controlled by TWO switches.

The Hampton Wall Switch I am trying to install has three wires (black and black and green)

There appears to be 4 wires coming out of the wall for the fan/light (black, red, white, and it looks to be another white wire, but that could be paint? Ground?)

The way it is CURRENTLY wired is:
Black Wire #1 comes from Wall and goes into BOTTOM of FAN Switch.
Black Wire #2 piggy tails from main group of Black Wires into TOP of FAN Switch.
Black Wire #3 piggy tails from main group of Black Wires into BOTTOM of LIGHT Switch.
Red Wire #1 comes from Wall and goes into TOP of LIGHT Switch.

Here is a picture of the wall switch diagram:
[image: Wall Switch Wiring Diagram]

Current wiring:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the control with the new fixture, you'll have to only use a the single "switch" to control it. This means you'll have to replace one of the switches with a blank insert, or not use the control module.

[image]
<sup>*Decora blank insert*</sup>

In the switch box, wire the new switch as follows:

- Black wire #2 (the one that comes from the black group, and goes to the top of the fan switch), connects to one of the black wires of the new switch.
- Black wire #1 (the one that comes from the wall, and goes to the bottom of the fan switch), connects to the other black wire from the new switch.
- Black wire #3 is either removed, or capped off using a twist-on wire connector of appropriate size.
- Red wire #1 is capped off using a twist-on wire connector of appropriate size.
- Connect the green ground wire from the new switch in with all the other bare grounding wires.

The wiring at the new fan will be as follows:

- Connect the white wire from the ceiling, to the white wire of the fan control module.
- Connect the black wire from the ceiling, to the black wire of the fan control module.
- Connect the green/bare grounding wire from the fan, to the grounding conductor from the ceiling.
- Cap off the red wire using a twist-on wire connector of appropriate size.
- Connect the black wire from the output of the control module, to the black wire from the fan.
- Connect the blue wire from the output of the control module, to the blue wire from the fan.
- Connect the white wire from the output of the control module, to the white wire from the fan.

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver! I wouldnt have figured that out on my own, and I have asked same question on multiple DIY forums, and have heard crickets. I really appreciate the clear and concise and detailed response. I am excited to try this tonight, and will post my results. Thanks so much!

Comment: So I tried this last night and the wall switch would not work... I wired it exactly as detailed in your post. The only deviation was wiring the receiver module in the fan. The fan DID NOT have a blue wire. The fan ONLY had 1 black wire and 1 white wire. I capped off the blue wire from the receiver module, and the red wire coming from the ceiling. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The fixture does not have a light?

Comment: Do you have the dip switches (or however the unit handles channels) set on both the switch and receiver? The installation manual should explain how to set them.

Comment: The fan does have an integrated light fixture. The fan claims to be operated by the remote only. Not sure what that means, but I am suspecting perhaps that is why it only has two wires? Here is link to fan: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Victoria-70-in-French-Beige-Ceiling-Fan-CL11012/203086249

Comment: The dip switches were both set on the wall switch unit and the receiver unit... Additionally I removed the receiver and the universal wall switch from the equation, and hooked it up to a normal single wall switch. The fan does work setup like this. The wall switch will turn power on and off, and the remote operates the fan speeds and light dimming.

Comment: Did you get it working?  It wasn't clear from the last comment.  If the setup works without the remote and receiver, I'd say it's a problem with those not the wiring.

Comment: If there's a light and a fan, there should be two wires from the receiver to the fixture (black and blue).

Comment: No I did not get it working with the Universal Remote Wall Switch. I got it to work with a "standard" single pole switch. The fan has a light, but only two wires black and white. =/

Comment: If the fan works with a standard snap switch, then the problem is with the remote/receiver. You'll have to try replacing one or both of them, and/or contacting Hampton Bay customer support.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I will have to contact customer support at Hampton since both the fan AND the universal wall switch are hampton bay products they should work together seamlessly.